# How to drop field from algorithm output in QGIS graphical modeler (drop fields does not work)

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I have built a process in the graphical modeler which uses several temporary outputs. The resulting CSV is fine but it contains an unneccessary field from the HubDistance algorithm (HubName). I'd like to be able to drop this from the output, but Drop Field(s) does not seem to work. When I open the CSV of the output, the field "HubName" is still there. Am I doing something wrong here? My process looks like this:

[image: Graphical modeler workflow]

[image: Drop Field(s) dialog]

Comment: I noticed you are using the "Pre-calculated value" option under Fields to drop, and have your field name in single quotes. I realised that I was using "Value" option and that I need to remove the single quotes from my field name with this option. It seems both your method and mine work but not if they are mixed.

Comment: OK, added that as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the input for `Fields to drop` to `Pre-calculated value` (the `ε` icon) and add the name of the field in single quotes (`'`). Like this, the field will be dropped, see screenshot for a simplified model:

[image: Screenshot]